can we get all tweets of the user from twitter using x gem rails
I am new to this rails community. Lately I am working on sceanrio for my side project where, I need to fetch tweets from twitter of particular user using Rails.
I have came down to these repo for fetching details(https://github.com/sferik/twitter-ruby), as this repo owner suggest to user x gem (https://sferik.github.io/x-ruby/) instead of twitter gem.
I gone through there documentation and configuration part but none of them explains flow for getting tweets from twitter.
I am just able to understand that this lines are important.
def configure_client(config)
  x_credentials = {
  access_token:        "Faker-UlxuwZAR98FWvxkD0B5xcPPZMqjInss5DcBT",
  access_token_secret: "JEYVGnsOnY0XPJcVLFakeryEV0rGGgL7oQ",
  api_key:             "9fKcWPDcFaker0kLX",
  api_key_secret:      "mBFakerkqGSdQI27HT03XZeVbbF2"
  }
  x_client = X::Client.new(**x_credentials)
end

Can anyone let me know is there any documentation or anything else we need to need to follow other than this

If those are your real tokens and API key you need to get new ones as those are now burned. Let this be a lesson into not hardcoding configuration into your code.

There are two different questions here.  The first being is "Is it possible?" to which the answer is almost always YES.  You can always resort back to using Net::HTTP or any of the gems that do Oauth and HTTP. The second is "Is there a gem that will do it all for me and which is maintained?" and that one is off topic.

@max definetly those creds are invalid creds as I have just added bunch of alphabets. I am looking for x gem integration to get tweets but documentation is not enough to build the app

See the API Docs for searching tweets: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/build-a-query. Most likely you want the from operator. I would recommend building the query string using the URI module because the x gem is very lightweight and appears to have a transparent but unfriendly interface.

@engineersmnky Hash#to_query from ActiveSupport is what you want. Build hashes and then convert to a string at the last second.

@max true. X's query interface appears to be very dynamic but incredibly awkward and cumbersome (primarily string based so there's limited gain from Hash#to_query v URI::encode_www_form. The gem boasts about its reduction in code footprint but leaves a lot to be desired from an OO standpoint (since it is basically just an extremely thin wrapper around net/http). Seems like it would greatly benefit from the addition of an AST and some formalized Objects.

Unfortunately, is no longer maintained.
If you check documentation: "The Twitter Ruby Gem is no longer maintained and will not support Twitter API v2"
And now I think you have to pay to use twitter API since it´s "X". You have like free demo to get few tweets.
By the way, I hope the tokens are not your and are fake or examples. If they are your tokens i recommend you to hide them here.
I will try to get some tweets with ruby and let you know.
I had it implemented some years ago, but now it has changed the game. Let´s see

Even if you edit out the credentials they will still be visable in the edit history. They need to generate new ones.

creds mentioned in question are definetly fakes one @Sebas
